# HttpURLConnection request showing up in Android Studio profiler but not reaching microcontroller

Tags: java, android, android-studio, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to access a local IP using an Android app with HttpURLConnection. The web server is working, I tested it with Postman. Using a microcontroller I can see when someone connects to that IP address, so I know it's something in my app that's not working.
I have the app set up so that it sends a POST request, and when I press the button the Android Studio profiler detects the request and shows the IP address, but it won't reach the microcontroller.

```
        String urlString = "http://192.168.2.115/request"; // URL to call
        OutputStream out = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
```

I enabled the INTERNET and the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions in AndroidManifest.xml and am not yet sending or receiving any data, just trying to access the IP address

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Edit: It works now, I needed to add conn.getInputStream(); after conn.connect, for whatever reason

Answer (score 1):

In which thread do you try to make http connection? Android system is prohibit to make network connection on main thread. Probably should use AsyncTask/RxJava/Thread.

Comment: I am using an AsyncTask. Before I did that, the app crashed when I tried to send the request. I also don't get any exception

Comment: it works now, needed to add conn.getInputStream(); for whatever reason